# Nginxのlocationで、固定ディレクトリ以下の任意のパスを、2階層まで順番にキャプチャ取得したい

Tags: nginx, 正規表現

**キャプチャ取得したいURLパス**
・/hoge/test/ディレクトリ以下の2階層までを順番にキャプチャ取得したい

**分からないこと**
・指定階層以下にスラッシュが含まれたURLだと、キャプチャ順番がずれてしまう

---

**試した内容**

```
location ^~/hoge/test/(.*)/(.*)/ {
```

---

**意図した通り取得できるURL**
・$1$2でab取得

> /hoge/test/a/b/

・$1$2でcd取得

> /hoge/test/c/d/e

**意図した通り取得できないURL**
・$1$2でfg取得したいのに、ghを習得してしまう

> /hoge/test/f/g/h/

---

**Q**
・下記URLで、常に$1で任意1、$2で任意2を取得するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

> /hoge/test/任意1/任意2/◯/◯
>   /hoge/test/任意1/任意2/◯/◯/
>   /hoge/test/任意1/任意2/◯/◯/◯/◯/◯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

条件を`.*`とした場合、`.`(任意の一文字)には`/`も含まれ、かつ`*`は「最長マッチ」を行うので、なるべく長いパターンにマッチしようとしてうまくいかないのだと思います。

個々のディレクトリ名にマッチさせたいのであれば、以下の様なパターンになるのではないでしょうか。

```
/hoge/test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

- `[ ]`がカッコの中の任意の一文字、その中の1文字目が`^`なので否定、2文字目に`/`があるので、`[^/]`は**スラッシュを含まない任意の一文字**
- `+`は直前のパターンの1回以上の繰り返しなので、`[^/]+`で**スラッシュを含まない1文字以上の文字列(=ディレクトリ名)**

Comment: 期待通り動作しました！ 「最長マッチ」が原因だとは全く気が付きませんでした。パターンにマッチさせる方法は色々あるのですね